# Need help to create a c# bubblesort. Whats wrong with what i have so far?

Tags: c#, sorting, quicksort, bubble-sort

I am trying to use a bubble sort, to order numbers from least to greatest in c#, whats wrong with what i have so far?

```
private void Order_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  value1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
  value2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
  value3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
  value4 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
  value5 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);

  int[] myarray = { value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 };
  int n = 0;
  bool swapped = true;
  int j = 0;
  int tmp;
  while (swapped) {
    swapped = false;
    j++;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++)
    {
      if (myarray[i] > myarray[i + 1]) {
        tmp = myarray[i];
        myarray[i] = myarray[i + 1];
        myarray[i + 1] = tmp;
        swapped = true;
        order1.Text = Convert.ToString(myarray[0] + "," + 
                                       myarray[1] + "," + 
                                       myarray[2] + "," + 
                                       myarray[3] + "," + 
                                       myarray[4]);
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Well what makes you think that anything *is* wrong with it? What's going wrong when you run it?

Comment: The only reason I could see to write your own bubblesort is homework. Is this homework?  If it doesn't ***have*** to be bubble sort, just do this: `var items = new List<int>{ value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 }; items.Sort();`

Comment: Always try StackOverflow first, then Yahoo answers. http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120730130225AAkmMs0

Comment: @ user1564002 your question is right "whats wrong with what i have so far?"
but you should ask this question yourself whether you got a runtime error or ur values are not being swpped

Comment: Its not homework, I just want to use a bubble sort, because I am trying to learn it. And, @kashmirilegion can you clarify what "ur values are not being swpped" means? I am fairly certain that there is a runtime error, but can any of you see where exactly it is? And, is it wrong because I am somehow doing it in the wrong format?

Comment: @user1564002 An error that occurs during the execution of a program is a runtime error.Runtime errors indicate bugs in the program or problems that the designers had anticipated but could do nothing about. For example, running out of memory will often cause a runtime error.
"I am fairly certain that there is a runtime error". so now tell whats the runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

First thing which is wrong with your code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++)
```

Your check `i < n - j` will never let the control to fall through the loop. Because you have initialized n to 0 and j is 1 (after j++), so `i`  is not going to be less then `-1`, Thus your loop will not work as intended. Since you set the swapped to false, the control will fall out of the while loop, hence no sorting.

You need to change your code to:

```
  while (swapped)
            {
                swapped = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < myarray.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (myarray[i] > myarray[i + 1])
                    {
                        int t = myarray[i];
                        myarray[i] = myarray[i + 1];
                        myarray[i + 1] = t;
                        swapped = true;
                        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(myarray[0] + "," + myarray[1] + "," + myarray[2] + "," + myarray[3] + "," + myarray[4]));
                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: I tried, this a somehow it still isn't working, I think the problem may be on the array itself, can you take a look at it and tell be whats wrong?

Comment: I figured out that the array always has a value of 5, so the loop never goes through, how do i fix that?

Comment: @user1564002, try replacing your while loop code with the one in the answer. It is working

Answer (score 0):

the `n` and `j`  variables seem unnessesary. leave `n` and `j` out of your program, and in your for loop, do this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < (array1.Length - 1); i++)
```

Answer (score -2):

**Bubble Sort**

```
using System;  

class AscendingBubbleSort 
{     
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = 0,j = 0,t = 0;
        int []c=new int[20];
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Value p[{0}]:", i);
            c[i]=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        // Sorting: Bubble Sort
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<20;j++)
            {
                if(c[i]>c[j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("c[{0}]={1}, c[{2}]={3}", i, c[i], j, c[j]);
                    t=c[i];
                    c[i]=c[j];
                    c[j]=t;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Here comes the sorted array:");
        // Print the contents of the sorted array
        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("c[{0}]={1}", i, c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[source](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4461)